# Gradient of squared riemannian distance on complete manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $\theta: M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$ the squared distance function $\theta(x,y)=d(x,y)^{2}$ on complete Riemannian manifold $M$. I would like to calcule the gradient of $d^{2}$, where $d^{2}_{y}(x)=d^{2}(x,y)$, for $x,y\in M$ such that $x \notin Cut(y)\cup \{y\}$. The idea is to consider $\alpha(t,s)$ a variation through geodesics of a minimizing geodesic $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(0)=y$ and $\gamma(l)=x$, $l=d(x,y)$ and if $L(s)$ denotes the length of the geodesic $t \to \alpha(t,s)$ , then by first variation formula :

$$\frac{d L(s)}{ds}\Bigr|_{s=0}= \langle V,T\rangle^{l}_{0} - \int\limits^{l}_{0} \langle V, \nabla_{T}T\rangle dt$$

where $T=\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial t}$ and $V=\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial s}$. Now , since $\alpha$ os geodesic $\nabla_{T}T=0$, and taking $\alpha$ such that $V$ is the Jacobi Field such that $V(0)=0$ and $V(l)=v$, where $v \in T_{x} M$ , thus :

$$\frac{d L(s)}{ds}\Bigr|_{s=0}=\langle v,T(l)\rangle.$$

Now, I have one question

$(1)$ Why $T(l)=\frac{-1}{l}exp^{-1}_{x}(y)$?

Thanks

Comment: I see only one question.

Comment: Post edited @Deane

Comment: T is the unit tangent to $\gamma$ joining $y$ to $x$ so $-T$ is the unit tangent to the geodesic joining $x$ to $y$. Thus $y = \exp_x(-\ell T(\ell))$.